# Google.com navbar Replica

Tags: html, css

So, I've been building my portfolio and the first project I chose was a simple replica of the google homepage. All else seems fine for now but for the life of me I can't get the navbar elements vertically centered and aligned. I tried using different displays, tried the vertically-align property in every single li but no dice.
Following is the code:

```css
#top_navbar {
  outline: none;
  margin: 10px 25px;
  float: right;
  font-size: 10%;
}

ul {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: flex;
  direction: row-reverse;
  list-style-type: none;
  top: 30px;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

i {
  color: black;
}

i.account {
  height: 200px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.Images {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

a.Gmail {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.material-icons.notifications {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
  background-color: grey;
  top: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.material-icons.apps {
  font-size: 32px;
  color: grey;
}

.material-icons.account {
  font-size: 48px;
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="top_navbar">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin" class="Gmail" target="_blank">Gmail</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://images.google.ca/" class="Images" target="_blank">Images</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div onclick="myFunction()"><i class="material-icons apps">apps</i></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><i class="material-icons notifications">notifications</i></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><i class="material-icons account">account_circle</i></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include, in your snippet, a link to the CSS file that provides the `material-icons` class. There's no way to reproduce this without them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a `line-height` to the `li` elements.

```
li {
    line-height: 32px;
}
```